# Custom packaging fails nexus release deployment

Tags: maven

I'm trying to set up a release plugin in a maven project but it fails at deployment of release artifacts in `release:perform`. The Nexus repository returns `400` and the maven log tells me that the binary is installed twice to my local repo and then also attempted to be uploaded twice.

I get the feeling that it's related to a custom (3rd party) packaging I'm using - but due to business reason I cannot reveal the name of this.

Anyone that think of a "typical" packaging error that would fool maven to install and deploy the jar twice? other artifacts like javadocs, sources etc do not suffer the sample problem.

Comment: output effective pom.xml here

Comment: There is nothing in the `pom.xml` but the `maven-release-plugin` (distMgr+scm) and the third party plugin. And of course the custom packaging notation - but I cannot post that. The release plugin has `<preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>`

Comment: If it helps in any way - I could fill in that the same thing happens on a regular `install` (but since it installs in local repo, the build doesn't fail). It doesn't seem related to the release-plugin.